# libtask on the iPhone

Tags: iphone

Has anyone gotten 'libtask', http://code.google.com/p/libtask/, running on the iPhone device? It seems to run we enough on the iPhone simulator but does not like running on the device at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this before,

see https://github.com/wsxiaoys/libtask

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but what is the benefit of running libtask over using the existing thread or GCD constructs?

Comment: libtask is portable across multiple platforms. GCD, for the moment is still primarily on OS X and iPhone. I'm trying to port some code to the iPhone that uses libtask.

Comment: Hmm, GCD is open source, perhaps you'd be better off porting GCD to the other platform and port the code to use GCD... :-)  Good luck.

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but if it can offer coroutine, I can gain deterministic/lightweight concurrent execution contexts. Which are can't be gained with kernel thread or GCD.